# Filling input label from Browser extension with jQuery

Tags: jquery, browser-extension

```
$('#email').val('user@email.com').trigger('change');
```

Trying to fill the input field with this line, The code working perfectly (Fill the from and active the button) on chrome & other browser console.

When running from exnantiosn this code fill the from but did't active the button.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from someone and the solution is:

`$('#email').val('user@email.com').get(0).dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('change'));`

This code input the val on the input field and active the button from browser extension.